# Is there a way to install vscode extensions in a Dockerfile?

Tags: vscode-remote

I am using docker-compose to spin up a dev environment. I would like to build out the dev image to include the needed vscode extensions. This would allow me to not have to manually go install the extensions every time a new image is build for a development container.

Is there anyway to download and get the extensions in place during the docker build process?

Comment: Are you using a `.devcontainer` folder approach, or doing an attach on a running container or something other?

Comment: I am using attach to a running container. Mainly because I couldn't find a way to override the project name used by vscode when spinning up a docker compose project.

Comment: Did you found a solution?